# Why will mobile users be redirected to the splash when im trying to exclude them from viewing this page

Tags: php, android, iphone, wordpress, mobile

Why are mobile users redirected to the splash when i'm trying to exclude them from viewing this page.  I just want desktop users to be redirected to this splash and not the mobile users.

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Splash Page Hooks and Filters
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Get the user agent strings.
$ipod = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iphone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$ipad = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"android");
$windowsphone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"IEMobile");
if( ! function_exists( 'custom_splash' ) )  {
    function custom_splash( $username ) {
        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // where did the user come from?
    // If not mobile user.
    if ($ipod == false || $iphone == false || $ipad == false || $android == false || $windowsphone == false) {
            // if there's a valid referrer
        if ( empty($referrer) && ( is_front_page() || is_home() ) ) {
            wp_redirect( '/splash/' ); // Redirect to the splash page.
        }
    } else {
    }

    return $referrer;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_splash' ); // hook splash page
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code is here, i used **&&** when i should have used **||**. also I moved the position of the if conditional.

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Login Hooks and Filters
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$ipod = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iphone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$ipad = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"android");
$windowsphone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"IEMobile");
$isDesktop = false;

if (!$ipod && !$iphone && !$ipad && !$android && !$windowsphone) {
    $isDesktop = true;
}

if ($isDesktop) {
    //  echo "Desktop True";
    if( !function_exists( 'custom_splash' ) )  {
        function custom_splash( $username ) {
            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
            if ( empty($referrer) && ( is_front_page() || is_home() )) {
                wp_redirect( '/splash/' ); // Redirect to the splash page.
            }
            return $referrer;
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_splash' ); // hook splash page
```